# Passing data to StatefulWidget and accessing it in its state in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget, pass-data

I have 2 screens in my Flutter app: a list of records and a screen for creating and editing records.

If I pass an object to the second screen that means I am going to edit this and if I pass null it means that I am creating a new item. The editing screen is a Stateful widget and I am not sure how to use this approach https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/passing-data/ for my case.

```
class RecordPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Record recordObject;

  RecordPage({Key key, @required this.recordObject}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RecordPageState createState() => new _RecordPageState();
}

class _RecordPageState extends State<RecordPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   //.....
  }
}
```

How can I access **recordObject** inside **_RecordPageState**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data to a Stateful Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818770/passing-data-to-a-stateful-widget)

Comment: how can we use 'recordObject' variable value in a function of _RecordPageState class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass StatefulWidget data to the State class without using constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428708/pass-statefulwidget-data-to-the-state-class-without-using-constructor)

Comment: **All the answers** except the last one made by G. Debailly  **are wrong**. Never use access to `context.widget` to retrieve what-you-assume-is-parent's data. For the *parent may be quite unexpected one*. E.g. in ListView it might be a SliverChildBuilderDelegate. Indead follow G. Debailly advice and learn [Simple app state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) article.

Answer (score 515, accepted):

To use recordObject in _RecordPageState, you have to just write widget.objectname like below

```
class _RecordPageState extends State<RecordPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   .....
   widget.recordObject
   .....
  }
}
```

Comment: Those who are new to Flutter, do not forget to define widget like '@override
  RecordPage get widget => super.widget;'

Comment: @hhk Why is that necessary?

Comment: Should't the `recordObject` be part of the `State` class? Logically, having it in `StatefulWidget` is incorrect (in terms of cohesion). Besides, all fields of `StatefulWidget` should be immutable - what if you want to change the `recordObject` reference?

Comment: I have exactly the same and it's not working doing something like `Text(widget.recordObject)`, it says that my var is null

Comment: how can we use 'recordObject' variable value in a function of _RecordPageState class?

Comment: It does not seem necessary to define the widget as in @hhk's comment anymore.

Comment: What if I want to change the field in RecordPage at runtime? Is pass the field to State class as an constructor argument is a better way?

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. See my comment to question.

Answer (score 128):

### **Full Example**

You don't need to pass parameters to State using it's constructor.
You can easily access these using **widget.myField**.

```
class MyRecord extends StatefulWidget {
  final String recordName;
  const MyRecord(this.recordName);

  @override
  MyRecordState createState() => MyRecordState();
}

class MyRecordState extends State<MyRecord> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.recordName); // Here you direct access using widget
  }
}
```

**Pass your data when you Navigate screen :**

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyRecord("WonderWorld")));
```

Comment: This is already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289032/12483095) many years ago. Please read other answers before writing yours.

Comment: What if I need change its value?

Answer (score 52):

```
class RecordPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Record recordObject;

  RecordPage({Key key, @required this.recordObject}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RecordPageState createState() => new _RecordPageState(recordObject);
}

class _RecordPageState extends State<RecordPage> {
  Record  recordObject
 _RecordPageState(this. recordObject);  //constructor
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {.    //closure has access
   //.....
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why this is a statefull widget.

Comment: @atilkan because OP initial script is a StatefulWidget, he just added some lines to fit the needs.

Comment: I do not think that having `recordObject` field both in `State` and `StatefulWidget` classes is such a good idea (even though I saw tutorials doing exactly this). The approach of accessing fields of `StatefulWidget` by using `widget` field of `State` class seem like a more correct approach (even though it has its own problems)

Comment: This implementation gives [no_logic_in_create_state](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/no_logic_in_create_state) lint warning

Answer (score 14):

example as below:

```
class nhaphangle extends StatefulWidget {
  final String username;
  final List<String> dshangle;// = ["1","2"];
  const nhaphangle({ Key key, @required this.username,@required this.dshangle }) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _nhaphangleState createState() => _nhaphangleState();
}

class _nhaphangleState extends State<nhaphangle> {
  TextEditingController mspController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController soluongController = TextEditingController();
  final scrollDirection = Axis.vertical;
  DateTime Ngaysx  = DateTime.now();
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

  ApiService _apiService;
  List<String> titles = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _apiService = ApiService();
    titles = widget.dshangle;  //here var is call and set to 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for where i can modify the values on the second page.

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to create any new object or variable for this reason in the state class, you need to define just a **final** and **nullable** variable for your object in the stateful class.
you can access this variable by `widget.` like `widget.recordObject`

```
class RecordPage extends StatefulWidget {
   final Record? recordObject;
   RecordPage({required this.recordObject});
   @override
   _RecordPageState createState() => new _RecordPageState();
}

class _RecordPageState extends State<RecordPage> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Text(
         widget.recordObject == null? "the object is null" : "the object isn't null",
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have to Navigate back to any one of the screens in the list pages but when I did that my onTap function stops working and navigation stops.

```
class MyBar extends StatefulWidget {
  MyBar({this.pageNumber});
  final pageNumber;
  static const String id = 'mybar_screen';
  @override
  _MyBarState createState() => _MyBarState();
}

class _MyBarState extends State<MyBar> {
  final List pages = [
    NotificationScreen(),
    AppointmentScreen(),
    RequestBloodScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _selectedItemIndex = widget.pageNumber;
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
          selectedItemColor: Color(kAppColor),
          selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Color(kAppColor)),
          currentIndex: _selectedItemIndex,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedItemIndex = index;
            });
          },
```

Answer (score 1):

In my app, often instead of using stateful widgets,  I use mainly `ChangeNotifierProvider<T>` in main.dart, some model class

```
class FooModel extends ChangeNotifier {

var _foo = false;

void changeFooState() {
   _foo = true;
   notifyListeners();
}

bool getFoo () => _foo;

}
```

and

```
var foo = context.read<FooModel>();
# or
var foo = context.watch<FooModel>();
```

in my stateless widgets.  IMO this gives me more precise control over the rebuilding upon runtime state change, compared to stateful widgets.

The recipe can be found in the official [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple), the concept is called "lifting state up".

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Pub/Sub mechanism.
I prefer to use Rx in many situations and languages. For Dart/Flutter this is the package: https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart

For example, you can use a **BehaviorSubject** to emit data from **widget A**, pass the stream to **widget B** which listens for changes and applies them inside the **setState**.
Widget A:

```
// initialize subject and put it into the Widget B
BehaviorSubject<LiveOutput> subject = BehaviorSubject();
late WidgetB widgetB = WidgetB(deviceOutput: subject);

// when you have to emit new data
subject.add(deviceOutput);
```

Widget B:

```
// add stream at class level
class WidgetB extends StatefulWidget {
   final ValueStream<LiveOutput> deviceOutput;
   const WidgetB({Key? key, required this.deviceOutput}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   State<WidgetB> createState() => _WidgetBState();
}

// listen for changes
@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();

   widget.deviceOutput.listen((event) {
      print("new live output");
      setState(() {
         // do whatever you want
      });
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will clear your doubt :-

```
class RecordPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Record recordObject;

  RecordPage({Key key, @required this.recordObject}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RecordPageState createState() => new _RecordPageState();
}

class _RecordPageState extends State<RecordPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Text(widget.record)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `State` class from `initState()` if you need to set initial value to your state variables from the `StatefulWidget`

```dart
class _RecordPageState extends State<RecordPage> {

  Record _recordObject;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _recordObject = widget.recordObject;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   //.....
  }
}
```