# Passing Data to a Stateful Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget, pass-data

I'm wondering what the recommended way of passing data to a stateful widget, while creating it, is.

The two styles I've seen are:

```
class ServerInfo extends StatefulWidget {

  Server _server;

  ServerInfo(Server server) {
    this._server = server;
  }

  @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _ServerInfoState(_server);
}

class _ServerInfoState extends State<ServerInfo> {
  Server _server;

  _ServerInfoState(Server server) {
    this._server = server;
  }
}
```

This method keeps a value both in `ServerInfo` and `_ServerInfoState`, which seems a bit wasteful.

The other method is to use `widget._server`:

```
class ServerInfo extends StatefulWidget {

  Server _server;

  ServerInfo(Server server) {
    this._server = server;
  }

  @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _ServerInfoState();
}

class _ServerInfoState extends State<ServerInfo> {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      widget._server = "10"; // Do something we the server value
      return null;
    }
}
```

This seems a bit backwards as the state is no longer stored in `_ServerInfoSate` but instead in the widget.

Is there a best practice for this?

Comment: The constructor can be reduced to `ServerInfo(this._server);`

Comment: This questioned have been asked earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428708/is-there-a-easy-way-to-pass-statefultwidget-class-variable-value-to-state-class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data to StatefulWidget and accessing it in it's state in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287995/passing-data-to-statefulwidget-and-accessing-it-in-its-state-in-flutter)

Comment: This answer is added one month before this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428708/pass-statefulwidget-data-to-the-state-class-without-using-constructor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass StatefulWidget data to the State class without using constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428708/pass-statefulwidget-data-to-the-state-class-without-using-constructor)

Answer (score 526, accepted):

Don't pass parameters to `State` using it's constructor.
You should only access the parameters using `this.widget.myField`.

Not only editing the constructor requires a lot of manual work ; it doesn't bring anything. There's no reason to duplicate all the fields of `Widget`.

**EDIT :**

Here's an example:

```
class ServerIpText extends StatefulWidget {
  final String serverIP;

  const ServerIpText ({ Key? key, this.serverIP }): super(key: key);

  @override
  _ServerIpTextState createState() => _ServerIpTextState();
}

class _ServerIpTextState extends State<ServerIpText> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.serverIP);
  }
}

class AnotherClass extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ServerIpText(serverIP: "127.0.0.1")
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: A further comment, anything you pass to a State object through the constructor won't ever get updated!

Comment: And here I am and don't understand the comment. "Don't pass parameters to State using it's constructor". So how do I pass parameters to the State?

Comment: @Rexford `State` already as access to all the properties of `Stateful` by using the `widget` field.

Comment: @RémiRousselet What if I want to use foo to pre-fill a textfield, and still allow the user to edit it. Should I also add another foo property in the state?

Comment: It worked for me, Thanks. But initially, my values were not updating and I still don't know why. Please, where can I read more on this? And why won't any object get updated through the constructor when passing data to a stateful widgets@JonahWilliams

Comment: @user6638204 You can create another foo property in the state, and override `void initState()` on state to set initial value. Check this [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/flutter-dev/zRnFQU3iZZs/ThAfrMfyBwAJ)  option C as example.

Comment: @user6638204 I think you should do it, but also you don't need to call 
setState(( 
) {})
because you don't need to rebuild the container(your page widget) of the textField widget , the textfield is rebuilding itself while typing

Comment: It did not work for me. The widget first renders for initial default state of foo, and then, on top of it, renders for one that passed in parameter.

Comment: @RémiRousselet I know it's a bit offtopic but still: why do all samples and tutorials use optional parameters while Dart may have required parameters as well - just without brackets `{` and `}`. Normally, if I add parameters I intend to use them so I don't want to wonder if they were passed or not, most of the time they are mandatory.

Comment: @KirillKarmazin it's just a good practice for readability. Soon Dart will have named required parameters.

Comment: @RémiRousselet got it, thank you. By the way, Dart already has `@required` annotation for optional named parameters, guess I'll use it for now

Comment: please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218265/discussion-about-complex-ui-with-widgets

Comment: On other hand, keeping all the objects in widget instead of state seems weird.

Comment: @JonahWilliams, if you want to change variable you can use it in **initState()**  instead of using in **build** function,

Comment: I want to add create  the constructor with a function pointer so the child  can programatically set the boottomnavbar selection which belongs to the parent.  I think this is the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 69):

**Best way** is don't pass parameters to State class using it's constructor. You can easily access in State class using **`widget.myField`**.

**For Example**

```
class UserData extends StatefulWidget {
  final String clientName;
  final int clientID;
  const UserData(this.clientName,this.clientID);

  @override
  UserDataState createState() => UserDataState();
}

class UserDataState extends State<UserData> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Here you direct access using widget
    return Text(widget.clientName); 
  }
}
```

**Pass your data when you Navigate screen :**

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserData("WonderClientName",132)));
```

Answer (score 22):

Another answer, building on @RémiRousselet's anwser and for @user6638204's question, if you want to pass initial values and still be able to update them in the state later:

```
class MyStateful extends StatefulWidget {
  final String foo;

  const MyStateful({Key key, this.foo}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulState createState() => _MyStatefulState(foo: this.foo);
}

class _MyStatefulState extends State<MyStateful> {
  String foo;

  _MyStatefulState({this.foo});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(foo);
  }
}
```

Comment: We  can directly use initState to do something like foo = widget.foo, no passing to constructor is required

Comment: How to pass argument to this ?

Comment: @SteevJames the widget `MyStateful` has one optional named parameter (property) you can create this widget by calling `MyStateful(foo: "my string",)`

Comment: @Aqib the `initState` does not solve a problem in the following scenario:  for example, you created your Statefull widget with empty parameters and you're waiting for your data to load. When the data is loaded you want to update your Statefull widget with the fresh data and in this case when you call MyStatefull(newData) it's `initState()` won't be called! In this case `didUpdateWidget(MyStatefull oldWidget)` will be called and you would need to compare your data from argument `oldWidget.getData()` with `widget.data` and if it's not the same - call `setState()` to rebuild the widget.

Comment: @Aqib ... but this is more theoretical problem, since in the first place you wouldn't want to use Statful widget that depends only on the parameters, it's better to use simple Stateless widget instead. Secondly you better not show the widget at all when your data is not ready.

Comment: @kirill-karmazin can you elaborate more on the Stateless widget solution? what would you use instead? Is it a best practice from the Flutter team? Thank you

Comment: All these answers seem kinda wasteful - here, `foo` is kept in the widget after being used in the state creation, never to be used again.

Answer (score 21):

For passing initial values (without passing anything to the constructor)

```dart
class MyStateful extends StatefulWidget {
  final String foo;

  const MyStateful({Key key, this.foo}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulState createState() => _MyStatefulState();
}

class _MyStatefulState extends State<MyStateful> {
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    // you can use this.widget.foo here
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(foo);
  }
}
```

Comment: `you can use this.widget.foo here `
very underrated info. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 5):

Flutter's stateful widgets API is kinda awkward: storing data in Widget in order to access it in `build()` method which resides in `State` object  If you don't want to use some of bigger state management options (Provider, BLoC), use flutter_hooks (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) - it is a nicer and cleaner substitute for `SatefullWidget`s:

```
class Counter extends HookWidget {
  final int _initialCount;

  Counter(this._initialCount = 0);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counter = useState(_initialCount);

    return GestureDetector(
      // automatically triggers a rebuild of Counter widget
      onTap: () => counter.value++,
      child: Text(counter.value.toString()),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to define the stateful widget class as **immutable** which means defining all dependencies (arrival parameter) as final parameters. and getting access to them by `widget.<fieldName>` in the state class. In case you want to change their values like reassigning you should define the same typed properties in your state class and re-assign them in the `initState` function. it is highly recommended not to define any not-final property in your stateful widget class and make it a **mutable** class. something like this pattern:

```
class SomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  final String? value;
  SomePage({this.value});

  @override
  State<SomePage> createState() => _SomePageState();
}

class _SomePageState extends State<SomePage> {
  String? _value;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      _value = widget.value;
    });
  }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(_value);
 }
}
```

Comment: It is not correct to use `setState()` within `initState()`. `setState()` should only be used when you update the state later: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363774/importance-of-calling-setstate-inside-initstate

Answer (score 1):

@Rémi Rousselet, @Sanjayrajsinh, @Daksh Shah is also better. but I am also defined this is in from starting point.that which parameter is which value

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      String name = "Flutter Demo";
      String description = "This is Demo Application";
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: MainActivity(
            appName: name,
            appDescription: description,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MainActivity extends StatefulWidget {
      MainActivity({Key key, this.appName, this.appDescription}) : super(key: key);
      var appName;
      var appDescription;
    
      @override
      _MainActivityState createState() => _MainActivityState();
    }
    
    class _MainActivityState extends State<MainActivity> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.appName),
          ),
          body: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text(widget.appDescription),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To pass `data` to stateful widget, first of all, create two pages. Now from the first page open the second page and pass the data.

```
class PageTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String name;

  PageTwo ({ this.title, this.name });

  @override
  PageTwoState createState() => PageTwoState();
}

class PageTwoStateState extends State<PageTwo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Text(
         widget.title,
         style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
               ),
  }
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
          text: "Open PageTwo",
          onPressed: () {
                var destination = ServicePage(
                   title: '<Page Title>',
                   provider: '<Page Name>',
                );
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => destination));
                        },);
  }
}
```