# Variables are suddenly null in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've implemented a date selection in my flutter app. The selected date then gets displayed, but as soon as the focus changes, the selected `DateTime` object becomes `null` without any reason.

To store the `DateTime` and some other variables I've created an object which is stored as a final variable in the `StatefulWidget` class. This object also includes `Strings` which don't change when the `DateTime` becomes null.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smartyne/core/assignment.dart';

class AssignmentPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final bool editMode;
  final Assignment assignment;

  AssignmentPage(this.assignment, this.editMode);

  @override
  _AssignmentPageState createState() => _AssignmentPageState();
}

class _AssignmentPageState extends State<AssignmentPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        ...
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: "Title"),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  widget.assignment.title = value;
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),

              ...

              SizedBox(
                height: 16.0,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    child: Text(widget.assignment.deadlineAsString),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _showDatePicker();
                    },
                  ),

                  ...

                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  void _showDatePicker() async {
    final DateTime newDeadline = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: widget.assignment.deadline == null ? DateTime.now() : widget.assignment.deadline,
        firstDate: DateTime(1900),
        lastDate: DateTime(2099)
    );

    if (newDeadline != null && newDeadline != widget.assignment.deadline) {
      setState(() {
        widget.assignment.deadline = newDeadline;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

As shown above, the `DateTime` gets selected by a `DatePicker` and the result is then stored in the `assignment` object. But when you click on the `TextField` for the title, it suddenly turns null.

Example gif: https://gph.is/g/aKn7yqq

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use the declared variable inside state class like below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smartyne/core/assignment.dart';

class AssignmentPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _AssignmentPageState createState() => _AssignmentPageState();
}

class _AssignmentPageState extends State<AssignmentPage> {
  final bool editMode;
  final Assignment assignment;
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Container();

//access it like 
//Text(assignment.deadlineAsString),
//instead of
//Text(widget.assignment.deadlineAsString),

}
```

Comment: In that case, what is the benefit of keeping `AssignmentPage` a `StatefulWidget`?

Comment: this is a wrong approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818770/passing-data-to-a-stateful-widget/50818870

Comment: This is working now, but what would be a right and working solution?