# Passing data from one screen to other screen in Flutter is null

Tags: flutter, dart, materialpageroute

I have two screen, from one i want to pass a title string to another screen. This title can be sign in or sign up, pre decided in first screen. What I have tried:

```dart
Container(
  child: RaisedGradientButton(
    onPressed: () {
      print('Login clicked');
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => 
            MyApp(
              formMode: FormMode.LOGIN, 
              screenTitle: "Login",
            )
        ),
      );
    }, 
    textButton: "Login", 
    height: 55, 
    width : 200.0, 
    buttonTitleColor: Colors.white, 
    buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.red,
  )
),
```

Below is second screen with initialization steps:

```dart
enum FormMode { LOGIN, SIGNUP }

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: StatelessLanding(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  // In the constructor, require a Todo
  final FormMode formMode;
  final String screenTitle;

  MyApp({Key key, @required this.formMode, @required this.screenTitle}) 
    : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MyAppStateFul();
  }
}

class _MyAppStateFulState extends State<MyAppStateFul> {
  FormMode formMode;
  String screenTitle;

  _MyAppStateFulState(FormMode formMode, String screenTitle) {
    this.formMode = formMode;
    this.screenTitle = screenTitle;
  }
}
```

This is the place where I am using screen title:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var screenTitle = "Login";
  print('screen title is $widget.screenTitle');
  print('screen title is $this.screenTitle');
  print('screen title is $screenTitle');
}
```

Can experts please help me.
Thanks

Comment: I think the answer on this page can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818770/passing-data-to-a-stateful-widget

Comment: I think the answer on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818770/passing-data-to-a-stateful-widget can help you

Answer (score 0):

The code is a bit hard to follow however it looks like you forgot to pass the `screenTitle` from the `MyApp` class to the `MyAppStateful` widget.

In the code you listed above you have the following stateless widget:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  // In the constructor, require a Todo
  final FormMode formMode;
  final String screenTitle;

  MyApp({Key key, @required this.formMode, @required      this.screenTitle}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyAppStateFul();
  }
}
```

To me it seems you'll have to pass the `screenTitle` to the `MyAppStateFul` constructor in order to make it available in your stateful widget, like so:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyAppStateFul(screenTitle);
  }
```

Of course this also requires you to change the `MyAppStateFul`constructor to accept the `screenTitle` parameter if it doesn't already.

I think this should fix it for you.