# How does the stateful vs. stateless distinction affect when widgets will be rebuilt?

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

I am trying to understand how state and lifting state works in Flutter. In the code below I made a simple app where I tried to pass or lift a string and a function through multiple levels.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String data = 'MyApp class data';

  void setTextField(String s) {
    setState(
      () {
        data = s;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainApp(data, setTextField),
    );
  }
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String mainAppData;
  final Function setTextField;
  MainApp(this.mainAppData, this.setTextField);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(mainAppData)),
      body: Container(
        child: Level2(mainAppData, setTextField),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Level2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String level2Data;
  final Function setTextField;
  Level2(this.level2Data, this.setTextField);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Level3(level2Data, setTextField),
    );
  }
}

class Level3 extends StatefulWidget {
  final String level3Data;
  final Function setTextField;
  Level3(this.level3Data, this.setTextField);

  @override
  _Level3State createState() {
    print('Level3: $this.level3Data');
    return _Level3State(this.level3Data, this.setTextField);
  }
}

class _Level3State extends State<Level3> {
  String level3Data;
  Function setTextField;
  _Level3State(this.level3Data, this.setTextField);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          onChanged: setTextField,
        ),
        Text(level3Data),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When the app starts, the string `data` in the `_MyAppState` state class is passed to the `MainApp` StatelessWidget when `MainApp` is built. In a similar manner, info is passed then to `Level2` StatelessWidget and `Level3` StatefulWidget.

When the `TextField` in `Level3` changes, `setTextField` is triggered. `setTextField` is defined up in `MyApp` and I figured that when the String `data` changes (inside `setState()`) it should trigger rebuilding of *all* the widgets affected by the change.

The text in the `MainApp` widget (appBar) changes, showing `MainApp` was rebuilt as I expected. But nothing happens to the `Level3` widget; it's not rebuilt. The print statement in the `createState()` method does not execute, and the Text widget's text does not change.

Why doesn't the `Level3` StatefulWidget rebuild?

Comment: You should not add constructors to `State`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818770/passing-data-to-a-stateful-widget/50818870#50818870

Comment: Thanks Remi. In your link I see there is a comment "...anything you pass to a State object through the constructor won't ever get updated" Might that be connected to my question?

Comment: Yes, that is related. Do what this answer suggests (no constructor, use `widget` property instead). This should solve your issue

Comment: Yes, it did solve the issue! So, I guess the stateful widget object is not rebuilt--it is immutable, with `final` properties. But the State object's properties can change(?). If you explain what's going on as an answer below I will be happy to accept it. ... Thank you again for the kindness of replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, the stateful widget Level3 is already created at the given location in the tree.
And according to the contract of the [stateful widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html), 
It is the responsibility of the widget implementer to ensure that the State is promptly notified when such state changes, using State.setState. 
So in your case you need to have setstate in level3 to be notified of the change again. 
The rebuilding only happens at level 1 because setState is called .

The rebuilding process continues recursively until the description of the user interface is fully concrete.
In Level 3, the class has its own set of fields 
 String level3Data;
 Function setTextField; 
It means these need to be again set using SetState or if you do something like this then the widget building continues.

```
class Level3 extends StatefulWidget {
  final String level3Data;
  final Function setTextField;
  Level3(this.level3Data, this.setTextField);

  @override
  _Level3State createState() {
    print('Level3: $this.level3Data');
    return _Level3State();
  }
}

class _Level3State extends State<Level3> {
  // String level3Data;
  // Function setTextField;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext _) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          onChanged: widget.setTextField,
        ),
        Text(widget.level3Data),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. As I understand it, setState is in MyApp's state, but the widget MainApp (i.e., a different widget from where setState is located) _is_ rebuilt. I know this because the title text changes....Is my understanding off?

Comment: edited my answer a little bit :). I hope it helps your understanding.