# How to receive a parameter and use in initState within a stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stateful widget that has one method called in initialisation. I wanna know how to be able to get a parameter from the previous screen and pass it in initState to my initialisation method

```
class LabDetalheWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String path;

  const LabDetalheWidget({
    Key key,
    this.path,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818770/passing-data-to-a-stateful-widget?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can pass parameter like that

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String param;

  const MyWidget({
    Key key,
    this.param,
  }) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
    void initState() {
      print(widget.param);
      super.initState();
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      
    );
  }
}
```

#### Inside the state you can access the parameter like that

`print(widget.param)`

Comment: What is that Key

Comment: It's a good practice to pass it to the super of StatefullWidget. You can check documentation on what is a key.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html

Comment: well, I have this code to get that page: `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRoutes.LAB_DETALHE,
                            arguments: item.elemento != null
                                ? item.elemento.fullPath
                                : subPath);`

Comment: Where do I pass the parameter

Comment: I'm guessing you are using MaterialApp' onGenerateRoute method. So there you can pass the parameter. The you showed is correrct but you need to pass it one more time when you are creating the instance of your widget inside onGenerateRoute.

Comment: `              case AppRoutes.LAB_DETALHE:
                return MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) =>
                        LabDetalheWidget(path: settings.arguments,));`

Comment: I wrote this in generateRoute and still doesn't work

Comment: Do you get any error or what? The param is null inside the statefullwidget? Can we see the widget code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228997/discussion-between-armstrong-and-yobo).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanna pass data across routes.. If so then read this flutter cookbook's section you might get the idea
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data