# how to use a variable in another class in Flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, variables

I have a statfull class called 'Location' which get the location with Geolocatar and Im showing the location with this :

```
 Text(currentPosition!=null? '$currentPosition' : '----',),
```

and this is :

```
static Position? currentPosition;
```

and I have another class called 'WeatherApi' which Im using Openweathermap Api to get the weather . now I want to use the *currentPosition* in the api url

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=44.34&lon=10.99&appid={API key}
```

how can I use the ***currentPosition*** in the url? I have tried widget.variablename but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flutter, one way to pass a variable from one class to another is
Using a constructor: You can pass the variable as a parameter in the constructor of the class that needs the variable.
you can read the details in the official [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the location details through the constructor of the WeatherApi class. Create a final variable(currentPosition) in the WeatherApi class and make it as required and  when you navigate from Location screen to WeatherApi screen, in the

**Navigator.push(context, //your route => WeatherApi(currentPosition: currentPosition));**

and to use the variable, do ***widget.currentPosition*** in the WeatherApi class

[Check out this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818770/passing-data-to-a-stateful-widget-in-flutter)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global variable outside the '`Location`' widget as a '`currentPosition`',

```html
class Position {
  static String? currentPosition;
}
```

call from '`Location`' this variable and set it.

```html
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Position.currentPosition = 'currentPosition';
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: ((context) => LocationWidget()),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text('Click Me'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then call it again from '`WeatherApi`' and use it.

```html
class WeatherWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeatherWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<WeatherWidget> createState() => _WeatherWidgetState();
}

class _WeatherWidgetState extends State<WeatherWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(Position.currentPosition ?? 'null'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```