# Parsing Data to Stateful Widget

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to parse data from screen to another screen, the alocation screen has stateful widget, but I found error said that the data I want to parse isn't defined though I've defined it, please help..Thank you..

Here is my code,

```
    var data_id;
    if (_keyForm.currentState.validate()) {
      _keyForm.currentState.save();

      // var data = "wmsorders_id='" + data_id + "'";

      // var response = await RestService()
      //     .restRequestServiceGet(SystemParam.URL_UPCOMING, data);

      // print("response : " + response.body.toString());
      // UpcomingModel upcomingModel;

      // upcomingModel = UpcomingModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));

      try {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PickUp(
                data_id: data_id
                ))
              );
          Toast.show("Parsing: " + data_id, context,);
      } catch (e) {
        Toast.show("Error:something wrong", context,
            duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
      }

    }
  }
```

I try to parse the data here,

```
class PickUp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PickUpState createState() => _PickUpState();
}

class _PickUpState extends State<PickUp> {
  var data_id;
  PickUp({Key key, this.data_id});
}
```

And I got this error, 
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass StatefulWidget data to the State class without using constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428708/pass-statefulwidget-data-to-the-state-class-without-using-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add constructor in PickUp class

```
class PickUp extends StatefulWidget {
  final String data_id;
  PickUp({this.data_id});

  @override
  _PickUpState createState() => _PickUpState();
}
```

And then you can use `data_id` inside the build method as,

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.data_id);
  }
```