# parssing data with flutter stateful widget and using it

Tags: parsing, flutter, dart, widget, stateful

I want to use data parsed  with if statement before override,
how to do that?
I tried many way but didn't worked.
please help me.

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
  Function buttonFunction;
  String buttonName;
  MyButton(this.buttonFunction,this.buttonName);

  @override
  _MyButtonState createState() => _MyButtonState();
}

class _MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {

if (widget.buttonName == "ok"){
  int i =1;
}
else int i =2;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          widget.buttonFunction();
        },
        child: Text("${widget.buttonName}",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: This is not possible. Maybe explain what you are trying to accomplish and we can point you better in the right direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass StatefulWidget data to the State class without using constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428708/pass-statefulwidget-data-to-the-state-class-without-using-constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do most of your initializings in the `initState` method.

```
  int i;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.buttonName == "ok") {
      i = 1;
    } else
      i = 2;
    super.initState();
  }
```