# Flutter: Launch App B from App A with arguments

Tags: flutter

I want Flutter App A to launch Flutter App B passing in arguments.

I want Flutter App B to read these arguments passed by Flutter App A.

How do I do this in Flutter on both iOS & Android?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58767810/13055261

Comment: @FloW i think the question is how to launch another app from your app

Comment: Take a look at url_launcher package!

Answer (score 1):

if you know the package name you can do handle it this way
add this plugins to your pubspec

```
 device_apps:
android_intent:
url_launcher:

openAnotherApp (data) async
{String dt = data['hello there'] as String;
  bool isInstalled = await DeviceApps.isAppInstalled('com.another app');
if (isInstalled != false)
 {
    AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
      action: 'action_view',
      data: dt
  );
  await intent.launch();
 }
else
  {
  String url = dt;
  if (await canLaunch(url)) 
    await launch(url);
   else 
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
}
```

if you want to check app availability first use [flutter_appavailability](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appavailability)

If already installed then launch otherwise open link in WebView using url_launcher.

Comment: What about iOS?

Comment: to read your arguments you can check https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent . I'havent dug deep into this.Else you can always use platform channels