# how to fix the error : The getter 'email' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: email

Tags: flutter, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, dart, firebase-authentication

While trying to retreive authentication data from firebase, I am facing the error :
The getter 'email' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: email

even if this is no error in my code.

when the user sign in he will be redirected to home page:

Here is the code i am using home.dart (in which there is sidebar):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testa/bloc/navigation_bloc/navigation_bloc.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:testa/sidebar/sidebar.dart';
import 'package:testa/sidebar/sidebar_layout.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget with NavigationStates {

  const HomePage({Key key,@required this.user}) : super(key: key);
  final FirebaseUser user;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home ${user.email}'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('/users')
            .document(user.uid)
            .snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return checkRole(snapshot.data);
          }
          return LinearProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );

  }

  Center checkRole(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data == null) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('no data set in the userId document in firestore'),
      );
    }
    if (snapshot.data['role'] == 'admin') {
      return adminPage(snapshot);
    } else {
      return userPage(snapshot);
    }
  }

  Center adminPage(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return Center(
        child: Text('${snapshot.data['role']} ${snapshot.data['name']}'));
  }

  Center userPage(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return Center(child: Text(snapshot.data['name']));
  }
}
```

Here is the code of sign_in.dart if it might help even if it seems there is no issue there

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:testa/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testa/sidebar/sidebar_layout.dart';
import 'package:testa/sidebar/sidebar.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => new _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _email, _password;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                validator: (input) {
                  if(input.isEmpty){
                    return 'Provide an email';
                  }
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Email'
                ),
                onSaved: (input) => _email = input,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                validator: (input) {
                  if(input.length < 6){
                    return 'Longer password please';
                  }
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Password'
                ),
                onSaved: (input) => _password = input,
                obscureText: true,
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: signIn,
                child: Text('Sign in'),
              ),
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }

  void signIn() async {
    if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      try{
       FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)).user;
       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SideBarLayout(user: user)));

      }catch(e){
        print(e.message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when i change SideBarLayout by HomePage, it works fine, otherwise, i have an error under the first 'user'  (context) => HomePage(user: user,))); and it says (the named parameter 'user' is not defined

```
  void signIn() async {
    if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      try{
       FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)).user;
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(user: user,)));

      }catch(e){
        print(e.message);
      }
    }
  }
```

SideBarLayout.dart code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'sidebar.dart';
import 'package:testa/bloc/navigation_bloc/navigation_bloc.dart';

class SideBarLayout extends StatelessWidget {


  const SideBarLayout({Key key, this.user}) : super(key: key);
 final FirebaseUser user;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider<NavigationBloc>(
        create: (context) => NavigationBloc(),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            BlocBuilder<NavigationBloc, NavigationStates> (
              builder: (context, navigationState) {
                return navigationState as Widget;
              },
            ),
            SideBar(),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the email/password is correctn because firstly i sign up and the email is well stored in database, but just after it returns this error!

Comment: In the try-catch block of signInMethod try to print your email. As it seems your email filed is empty when you are passing data.put print(_email); at the start of try block . Check console and response to this comment with what you see in the console.

Comment: Where is your `SiderBarLayout`, it is same as the `HomePage`?

Comment: i have added that in this method and it shows me the email i used to log in and the same error again => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SideBarLayout(user: user)));
       print('Home ${user.email}');// line added in the method
      }catch(e){
        print(e.message);
      }
    }

Comment: @Adnankarim, its another class, so its not HomePage

Comment: Please edit your question and add the `SideBarLayout` class

Comment: @UTKARSHSharma printing `user.email` is of no use because the error indicates that the `FirebaseUser` object is `null`, not the email property.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your user data is not being passed to the HomePgae, first convert your HomePgae to StatfullWidget
Then make sure to add a constructor
Check this how to pass data to a StatfullWidget 
[Passing data to StatefulWidget and accessing it in it's state in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287995/passing-data-to-statefulwidget-and-accessing-it-in-its-state-in-flutter/50289032#50289032)

Comment: i converted this class to StatfullWidget, but i am not sure i understood the second step you have mentionned (make sure to add a constructor) even if i checked the link. thanks

Comment: I think its better to watch a video as its confusing little bit check  this video at the minute 6:30 but i advice you to watch the whole video https://youtu.be/d5PpeNb-dOY

Comment: @RidhaRezzag It's not necessary to change this to a stateful widget. `HomePage` doesn't have anything that would require `State`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this error is caused by invalid email/password and the `FirebaseAuth` is returning `null` and without checking you are Navigating to the next page and hence it throws an error.

1. Make sure you are providing correct credentials.
2. Before navigating to the `Homepage` check if the user is null or not?

---

```
FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)).user;
if(user!=null){
  // Navigate to Homepage
}
```

Comment: @yassinezagliz please attach debugger at the signin process and step through it to check the values and responses.

Comment: attached to the case

Comment: @yassinezagliz is the value of `user = null` in the console?

Comment: @Brendan no its not nul.