# Data not passing to second screen while using constructor

Tags: flutter

I was trying to send data got from a JSON response to a second screen from the main screen.
My widgets are placed in separate class files. I called a single API call to fetch all data from the API so that there won't be many API calls happening while opening the app.

But I can't pass the data to the second screen in arrMaincategories. What should I do?

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
    }
    
    class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
    var arrBanner = [];
      var arrImages = [];
      var arrMainCategories = [];
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        this.getBanner();
    
        setState(() {});
      }
    
      getBanner() async {
        String url = "https://www.clickxpress.in/api/";
    
        var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    
        var custID = prefs.getString('id');
    
        var response = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(url),
            body: (<String, String>{
              'type': "homepage",
              'secKey': "2a067feaeb67fgh89fyrc6657654fhjj9714b2094818f",
              'customerId': custID,
              'geoLat': "55.2324",
              'geoLong': "23.55556",
            })); //for accepting only json response
        setState(() {
          Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
          var data = map["attributes"];
    arrBanner = data['topBanner'];
          arrMainCategories = data['mainCategories'];
    if (arrBanner != null) {
            for (var value in arrBanner) {
              final image = value['imageUrl'];
              arrImages.add(NetworkImage(image));
            }
```

**Called It to a new screen**

```
NewCat(arrMainCategories: arrMainCategories),
```

**trying to fetch on 2nd screen**

```
class NewCat extends StatefulWidget {
  NewCat({Key key, @required this.arrMainCategories}) : super(key: key);
  final arrMainCategories;

  @override
  _NewCatState createState() => _NewCatState(arrMainCategories);
}

  
class _NewCatState extends State<NewCat> {
  var arrMainCategories = [];
  var arrCatImages = [];
  var arrCatName = [];

  _NewCatState(
    arrMainCategories,
  );
```

But the value is not coming here in the empty array. what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `Constructor`, You Can also access the *data* by using this line of `code`

```
print(widget.arrMainCategories);
```

*[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287995/passing-data-to-statefulwidget-and-accessing-it-in-its-state-in-flutter) resource link for more details*

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
_NewCatState(
    widget.arrMainCategories,
  );
```

instead of this

```
_NewCatState(
    arrMainCategories,
  );
```