# Passing data to a State from his Statefulwidget

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget, pass-data

this is my code and i want to access to "initialValue" propierty from the StatefulWudget but for some reason marks a error in `counter = widget.initialValue`
[the image with the error from vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBid0.png).
I'm following a course and i don't know if something change in the new versions, cause all the questions that i found use the same code.

```
class MyCounter extends StatefulWidget{


 final int initialValue;

  const MyCounter({Key? key, this.initialValue = 0}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State createState(){ //puede ser lamda => MyCounterState();
    return MycounterState();
  }
}

class MycounterState extends State{

  int counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    counter = widget.initialValue;
  }
...
```

Or do i have an error in a different part of the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data to StatefulWidget and accessing it in it's state in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287995/passing-data-to-statefulwidget-and-accessing-it-in-its-state-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for someone with the same problem the solution(found in the discord offical flutter server) was
"Your state must have a type argument containing the widget"

```
class MyCounter extends StatefulWidget{
  final int initialValue;

  const MyCounter({Key? key, this.initialValue = 0}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyCounter> createState(){ //puede ser lamda => MyCounterState();
    return MycounterState();
  }
}

class MycounterState extends State<MyCounter>{

  int counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    counter = widget.initialValue;
  }
```

just need to change `State` to `State<MyCounter>` in the "`createState()`" from MyCounter class and the "`extends State{`" from MyCounterState class