# Pass data from on screen to another screen for hive

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-hive

How can I send "records"  variable to another screen?

[image: Problem Image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data to StatefulWidget and accessing it in it's state in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287995/passing-data-to-statefulwidget-and-accessing-it-in-its-state-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

if you have a `SecondScreen()` you can pass data to it when you navigate to it from it's constructor like this

```
class SecondScreen extendsS StatelessWidget {
 SecondScreen(this.gotRecords);
 final Box? gotRecords;
/* more code*/
 }
```

and now when you try to navigate pass that `records` in that constructor like this :

```
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondScreen(gotRecords:records)),
 );
```

and from that screen you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

another solution is to just call the box wherever you want by its name

I see that your Hive box is called **Details**, so wherever you want to use that same box, just call simply from any screen in your app:

```
Box? records = Hive.box("Details");
```